# Cannot paste images from authenticated site to Microsoft Word

Tags: web, windows-8, ms-word, internet-explorer-10

I've seen this issue posted here before, but the solution - although it helped others - did not work for me.

When you copy an image from your browser into your clipboard, and then paste it into Word, Word tries to make a web request to get the content.  If the image was from a site that uses a form-based login to authenticate users, Word obviously fails to login.  Your content cannot be pasted.  Other software, like Paint for example, has no issue with this and will simply paste your copied content without trying to make another web request.

It has been suggested that changing the "Check for newer versions of stored pages" setting  in Internet Settings to "Automatically" will the solve the problem.  This may well work for some, but not for me.  I've tried every option in this setting and none work.

I've used packet capture software to ensure that Word really is making a web request when I paste the content. The web page is indeed redirecting Word to the authentication page, at which point, Word does nothing.

I am using Chrome, but have tried Internet Explorer.  My Internet Explorer version is 10.  I am using Windows 8.  I am using Word 2010.

There are many suggestions on the web about image formatting and document layouts etc. in Word, but this is clearly not my problem.  The packet capture reveals that Word cannot authenticate to get the image.

Is there some way to prevent Word from doing an extra HTTP GET to gather the image from the website?  Since other software has no problem pasting the content without doing an additional web request, it seems the content really is in my clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fight Word on this have you tried just saving the image itself and then copying your local copy to Word rather than copying it directly from the site? You would take ownership and Word should treat it like a local file and see no need do a HTTP GET.

Comment: This does work of course, but my issue is that my customers have fairly large amounts of content with a number of images scattered throughout.  They want to be able to select it all and paste it into Word.  Pasting each image in the right place after saving them all first will cost a lot of time. For this reason, as well as a few others, I am looking for a solution to this specific problem.  Thanks for the note!